# При деплое бота на хероку вылезает ошибка, что она значит и как ее исправить?

Tags: python, heroku

```
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote: -----> Installing python-3.7.13
remote: -----> Installing pip 22.0.4, setuptools 60.10.0 and wheel 0.37.1
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting aiofiles==0.7.0
remote:          Downloading aiofiles-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
remote:        Collecting aiohttp==3.7.4.post0
remote:          Downloading aiohttp-3.7.4.post0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
remote:        Collecting async-timeout==3.0.1
remote:          Downloading async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting asyncio==3.4.3
remote:          Downloading asyncio-3.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
remote:        Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
remote:          Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
remote:        Collecting Cogs==0.4.4
remote:          Downloading Cogs-0.4.4.tar.gz (18 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
remote:          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
remote:
remote:          × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
remote:          │ exit code: 1
remote:          ╰─> [1 lines of output]
remote:              error in Cogs setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
remote:              [end of output]
remote:
remote:          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
remote:        error: metadata-generation-failed
remote:
remote:        × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
remote:        ╰─> See above for output.
remote:
remote:        note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
remote:        hint: See above for details.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

Comment: линканите ваш файл requirements.txt

Comment: ```aiofiles==0.7.0
aiohttp==3.7.4.post0
async-timeout==3.0.1
asyncio==3.4.3
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
dislash.py==1.4.9
discord.py==1.7.3
disnake==2.3.0
glqiwiapi==1.0.4
Cybernator==0.6.3
discord-components==2.0.4
DiscordUtils==1.3.4
dnspython==2.1.0
gevent==21.1.2
greenlet==1.1.0
python-dotenv==0.20.0
grequests==0.6.0
hypixel==0.8.0
idna==2.10
multidict==5.1.0
numpy==1.21.0
Pillow==8.2.0
psutil==5.8.0
pymongo==3.12.0
pyshorteners==1.0.1
requests==2.25.1
simpledemotivators==2.0.1
urllib3==1.26.6
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
Cogs==0.4.4```

Comment: половина ваших модулей нуждается в обновлении, как могу судить. и pip тоже, хотя ошибка прямым текстом пишет что pip не причем. pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: сама проблема на хостинге, не на моем пк. а там пип всегда обновлен до последней версии (22.0.4)

Comment: т.е мне просто модули обновить все надо?

Comment: я бы начал с этого

Comment: я щас пробую это, спасибо

Comment: это не заработало ;(

Comment: вот мои библиотеки (я убрал версии, хостинг автоматически новые ставит) ```aiohttp
asyncio
ez-setup
beautifulsoup4
dislash.py
py-cord
glqiwiapi
Cybernator
DiscordUtils
dnspython
grequests
hypixel
numpy
Pillow
psutil
pymongo
requests
simpledemotivators
urllib3
Cogs```

Comment: я решил эту проблему установив python 3.6.13 на хостинг, там другая версия setuptools, спасибо что хотел помочь